# Minimal film area formula

Tags: calculus

How do we find minimum area of a symmetric soap film in terms of $ r,R, h ,$ when it is known the film surface has form swept out from

$ y = A \cosh ( B x) + C $

$ r =  A+ C, \; R= A \cosh Bh + C $ etc.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Try finding w=F(r,R,h) and find the multivariable derivatives. Then there is some other technique to minimize it just like with Lagrange multipliers or 1 variable calculus optimization. To get all of the equations into one add them to get y+r+R+etc.=A*cosh(Bx)+C+A+C+A*cosh(Bh)+C+etc. This is just an idea though, so it may not work.